# Materialize M is not defined

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

I am currently building a landing page which I want to use a component from Materialize which is collapsible.

I added the _collapsible.scss along with the collapsible.js to my project however I'm getting a few errors, which I'm not sure how to resolve.

Uncaught ReferenceError: M is not defined
    at HTMLDocument. (main.js:19)

Uncaught ReferenceError: cash is not defined
    at collapsible.js:275

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
    var instances = M.Collapsible.init(elems, options);
  });
```

```
<script src="scripts/materialize.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/collapsible.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/flickity.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
```

Cheers

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit rusty, but shouldn't you import `materialize.js` as well?

Comment: I just downloaded the sass package and it doesn't come with a materialize.js so I'm not sure..

Comment: According to [this](https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html) you should include the js as well.

Comment: I tried adding it in however it still stays with the same error.

Comment: Did you add it at the first import? If in that case you still have the same error I'm afraid I'm at a loss as to what is happening.

Comment: Yep, but still nothing, I am quite confused too, but thanks a lot for taking the time to help.